# What are the appropriate densities and temperatures of constituents of the universe after reheating?

Tags: cosmology, universe, cosmological-inflation

In slow roll inflation, the inflaton field has to decay into the currently observed constituents of the universe at the end of inflation. This process is called reheating. What are the experimental bounds on the densities and temperatures of each species resulting at the end of reheating? I mean, can specific numbers be given that must have been met to ensure that the universe could evolve into the state we find ourselves in today?